# Validate Nullable Enum Values using Fluent Validation

Tags: .net-6.0, fluentvalidation, c#-7.0

I have a nullable list of Enumeration and I would like to validate the enum only if the list is NOT null. I do see option to validate for `Null` & `IsInEnum`. But would like to do only if the employeeTypes `IS NOT NULL`. How can I achieve this?

```
public enum EmployeeType
{
    LEVEL_1 = 1,
    LEVEL_2 = 2,
    LEVEL_3 = 3,
    LEVEL_4 = 4
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployeesAsync(List<EmployeeType>? employeeTypes)
{
   //TODO: I want to move this to Fluent Validation
   if (employeeTypes!= null && employeeTypes.Any(x => !Enum.IsDefined(x)))
   {
    return BadRequest("employeeTypes parameter is Invalid");
   }
   
   //Return employees based on employeeTypes if not null, else return all employees
   var employees = await _engine.GetEmployes(employeeTypes);
   return Ok(employees);
}
```

Comment: [The default value of an enumeration type E is the value produced by expression (E)0, even if zero doesn't have the corresponding enum member.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#:~:text=The%20default%20value%20of%20an%20enumeration%20type%20E%20is%20the%20value%20produced%20by%20expression%20(E)0%2C%20even%20if%20zero%20doesn%27t%20have%20the%20corresponding%20enum%20member.)

Comment: @Luuk: I didn't understand what you meant. All I am trying to do is move the `if condition on the enumeration` to FluentValidation. Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: `employeeTypes` is of type `EmployeeType`, which is an `enum`. It will never have the value `null`, because it defaults to `0`.

Comment: `List<EmployeeType>?` is not the same as `List<EmployeeType?>`. Read more about nullable types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: @Prolog: That's exactly what I want. If the employeeTypes is null, I want to return all employees. But if it is not null, then I would like to return all the employees who fall into that filter. All I am asking is how can I convert `if (employeeTypes != null && employeeTypes.Any(x => !Enum.IsDefined(x)))` into fluent validation?

I want to validate the Enum.IsDefined only if the employeeTypes is not null

Answer (score 0):

I added a custom validation for the enumeration and worked around with this problem for now. Let me know if there is a better solution.

```
private static bool IsValidEmployeeTypes(List<LeadType>? employeeTypes)
{
    if (employeeTypes == null || employeeTypes.Count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return employeeTypes.All(Enum.IsDefined);
}
```

Then called the above method from the Validator function as below:

```
RuleFor(x => x.employeeTypes)
    .Must(IsValidEmployeeTypes)
    .WithMessage("Invalid value for employeeTypes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at:

```
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    
    EmployeeType a = new EmployeeType();
    EmployeeType? b = new EmployeeType();
    
    Console.WriteLine("a:{0} b:{1}", a, b);
    a = EmployeeType.LEVEL_2;
    b = EmployeeType.LEVEL_3;
    Console.WriteLine("a:{0} b:{1}", a, b);
    
    a = (EmployeeType)6;
    b = (EmployeeType)7;
    Console.WriteLine("a:{0} b:{1}", a, b);
    
    foreach(var item in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(EmployeeType))) {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
  
  public enum EmployeeType
{
    LEVEL_1 = 1,
    LEVEL_2 = 2,
    LEVEL_3 = 3,
    LEVEL_4 = 4
}
```

output:

```
Hello World
a:0 b:0
a:LEVEL_2 b:LEVEL_3
a:6 b:7
LEVEL_1, LEVEL_2, LEVEL_3, LEVEL_4,
```

see: https://onlinegdb.com/saNCB96Nmq

- The default value of an enum is not `NULL` (see: [link to learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#:%7E:text=The%20default%20value%20of%20an%20enumeration%20type%20E%20is%20the%20value%20produced%20by%20expression%20(E)0%2C%20even%20if%20zero%20doesn%27t%20have%20the%20corresponding%20enum%20member.) )

One could extend this example using a List, see: https://onlinegdb.com/zJN7LrnhX

Comment: It is not the enum which I am setting to null. It is the `List<enum>?`. I guess you didn't notice it...